# Does @Transactional automatically rollback transaction in Spring 3?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, transactions

I'm running as unit test and it automatically goes back even if I don't use the`@rollback` in spring 3.1.
My test looks like

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:application-context.xml" })
public class PersonServiceTest {

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void savePerson() {
            Person person = createPerson();
            personService.savePerson(person);
    }
}
```

Is Rollback behavior is set by default?

Comment: TL;DR: Yes, this is the default.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` will rollback transactions automatically.

To negate the effect, use `@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=false)` on your test class or `@Rollback(false)` on each test.

Comment: ...on Spring 5,  `@Commit` replaces `@Rollback(false)`